# How to toggle between bootstrap button classes onClick?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap buttons and would like them to change color when clicked. For example, the button is originally gray (btn-default) and should change to green (btn-success) on click. I would like the button to change back to the default class when clicked again. So far I have created an if statement and added the following code, however it is only changing color once, and will not return to the default class when clicked again.

```
$("#critical_btn").click(function () {

    if (this.class= 'btn-default'){
        $('#critical_btn').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success ');
        $(this).addClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-default');
    }
    else if (this.class= 'btn-success'){
        $('#critical_btn').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default ');
        $(this).addClass('btn-default').removeClass('btn-success');
    }
    });
```

I am fairly new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of doing and if elseif statement. If you want to toggle between two classes you can use $(selector).toggleClass('firstclass secondclass') as long as one on them will be assigned in the markup. (http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

jQuery would look like this:

```
$("#critical_btn").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-success');
});
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/xsotp27s/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hasClass` Method :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#critical_btn").click(function () {

         if ($(this).hasClass('btn-default')){
             $('#critical_btn').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
             $(this).addClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-default');   
         }

         else if ($(this).hasClass('btn-success')){
             $('#critical_btn').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
             $(this).addClass('btn-default').removeClass('btn-success');
         }

     })
 })
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .btn-success {background-color: red}
        .btn-default {background-color: blue}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="critical_btn" class="btn-default">Button</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {

         $("#critical_btn").click(function () {

             if ($(this).hasClass('btn-default')){
                 $('#critical_btn').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
                 $(this).addClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-default');   
             }

             else if ($(this).hasClass('btn-success')){
                 $('#critical_btn').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
                 $(this).addClass('btn-default').removeClass('btn-success');
             }

         })
     })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle classes like this:

```
$("#critical_btn").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-success'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#critical_btn").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("btn-success btn-default");
});`

Toggle class feature of jquery will help you out in this need.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/